# Why is the flag option "it doesn't belong here" missing?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags, flag-dialog

I'm trying to flag a question for closing in Stack Overflow. Why is "It does not belong here..  doesn't belong here because.." missing in the flag menu for Stack Overflow?

[image]

---

The same is present on others -

[image]

[image]

Comment: That seems like it's redundant to an off-topic close vote, but I don't know why it's not consistent across sites.

Comment: I should mention I don't have Vote to Close privs in Stack Overflow

Comment: Odd, I'm seeing the same behavior on [this "question"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93378/5-out-of-7-large-software-product-development-programs-products-never-see-the-lig).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't repro this. I think at the time you clicked *the question was actually closed* so that option is no longer available to you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128681/why-are-those-memory-leaks-in-firefox-still-not-fixed

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be the case. I can't repro on other questions either, except for the closed one.