# Missing option in flag popup

Tags: support, flags, flag-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the flag option “it doesn't belong here” missing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80796/why-is-the-flag-option-it-doesnt-belong-here-missing)

I wanted to flag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658812/benefits-of-white-labelling as off-topic, but the "it doesn't belong here" option is not available. I see this flag option on other Stack Overflow posts. Is this a bug? Based on selected tags maybe?

[image: screenshot]

The question is now closed, but I took this screenshot before it got closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it was closed between the time you loaded the page and clicked the flag link. The flag popup is loaded dynamically, therefore such a thing would have been possible.

The fact that you posted this question one minute ago, yet the post was closed more than 10 minutes ago would support this.

Comment: I think I reloaded the post again before clicking on 'flag' and it was not closed at that point but I can't confirm so I believe you are correct.

Comment: I think that would be the most logical explanation. Maybe have the devs confirm.